# How can i make grid control first time load faster using ngen

Tags: c#, ngen

i have a grid control in my C# application which loads slow for the time. takes up to 17 second after that starts to in a 1sec, the table has only 800 records. so i tried to use `ngen` by adding `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install “$(TargetPath)”` to speed up but i get the following error message. what did i miss?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The command
>   "%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install
>   “\server\XXX\pdm\pdm\project\bin\Debug\project.exe”" exited
>   with code -1. project

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee the performance problems are nothing to do with JIT Compilation. Have you tried debugging your app to see what calls are taking the longest amount of time to execute? Do you have a long running database query that fetches the data for your data grid?

Comment: @KidCode i am using master detail using devexpress. it was start running fast after i add ngen then after i start getting that error message starts load slow  again i dont know how ngen works. is it something related to permission?

Comment: @KidCode where is that error comes from